# glmnet variable importance | `vip` vs `varImp`

Tags: r, glm, glmnet

I fitted a Lasso Logistic Regression model using `glmnet`

```
X = data.matrix(mtcars %>% dplyr::select(-vs))
y = mtcars$vs
CV_lasso = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", type.measure = "class")
```

I was trying to determine variable importance and came across two methods that give widely different results

```
vip(CV_lasso$glmnet.fit)
```

```
varImp(CV_lasso$glmnet.fit, lambda = CV_lasso$lambda.min)
```

Could someone tell me what the difference is with these methods and which one is better? What is the best way to determine variable importance from a logistic lasso model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be because they use a different value for `lambda`. In `varImp`, you specify which `lambda` to use. However, when you call `vip`, then in the source code, the following code gets executed:

```
imp <- if (inherits(object, what = "vi")) {
    object
  } else {
    vi(object = object, ...)  # compute variable importance scores
  }
```

where `vi(object = object, ...)` gets called. In the source code for the `vi` function, at some point this tibble is defined:

```
tib <- switch(method,
    "model" = vi_model(object, ...),
    "firm" = vi_firm(object, feature_names = feature_names, var_fun = var_fun,
                     ice = ice, ...),
    "permute" = vi_permute(object, feature_names = feature_names, ...),
    vi_shap(object, feature_names = feature_names, ...)
  )
```

The problem arises with the definition of `"model"`. When trying to run `vi_model`. In this function this code is what finds out which lambda to use:

```
 # Extract coefficients
  s <- list(...)$s
  if (is.null(s)) {
    s <- min(object$lambda)
  }
```

Since you haven't defined what `s`, then it is set to be the minimum of you lambdas. That is the last value of lambda, which is 0.0001119218. This is not equal to the lambda used in your `varImp`, where you specify to use the optimal lambda, in this case 0.1586463.

You can get the same coefficients by running:

```
c1 = vip::vi_model(CV_lasso$glmnet.fit, s = CV_lasso$lambda.min)
c2 = caret::varImp(CV_lasso$glmnet.fit, lambda = CV_lasso$lambda.min)
```

and then if you insist on using `vip::vip` to get the plot, you can call this function on `c1`:

```
vip::vip(c1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you mind helping me with two more things? (1) What is "importance" here? (2) Why does `varImp` provide importance in absolute values whilst `vi_model` retains the sign? What is the difference here?

Comment: @Mistakamikaze Do you know the theory behind lasso regression? Your lasso regression in this case gives you a model, where ```vs``` is a function of ```cyl```, ```mpg```, ```disp``` and ```qsec```. The coefficients of ```qsec``` and ```cyl``` are a lot higher than the others, and hence I guess they could be considered more important for your predictions of ```vs```.  I don't have any experience with either of the two functions, so I can't say why one has chosen absolute values, and the other hasn't. I can't find any information on this in the documentations.